# How to choose pass instance method to use to a method in Java

Tags: java, java-8, instance-methods

I have a method that sorts a List by different criteria and returns the name (an instance variable) of the one with maximum value. In case more than one instance is having the maximum, all of their names should be concatenated.

Let's say I have Class A as follows.

```
Class A {
    ...
    String getName(){...}
    int getValue1() {...}
    int getValue2() {...}
    ...
    int getValueN() {...}
    ...
}
```

I have `a List<A> listToSort`. I would normally sort this list as `listToSort.sort(Comparator.comparing(A::getValue1))` or `listToSort.sort(Comparator.comparing(A::getValue2))`, so on and so forth. Then get the ones sharing the maximum value.

In a method I believe this should be done as:

```
String getMaxString (Comparator c) {
    listToSort.sort(c);
    ...
}
```

and send `Comparator.comparing(A.getValueX)` as parameter to call it with different methods. (X here indicates an arbitrary number for the getValue function).

However, I need to also return other instances sharing the same values
I will need to pass the Class methods to my method and call on instances as:

```
String getMaxString (Comparator c) {
    listToSort.sort(c);

    int maxValue = listToSort.get(listToSort.size() - 1).getValueX();
    String maxString = listToSort.get(listToSort.size() - 1).getName();

    for (int i = listToSort.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (listToSort.get(i).getValueX()() == maxValue) {
            maxString += ", " + listToSort.get(i).getName();
        }
    }
    return maxString;
}
```

How would I pass this method to call on instances here? Or do I need to consider another way?

**Edit**:

I have a list of Courses as `List<Course> mylist` where a course can be simplified as:

```
Class Course {
    private String name;
    private int capacity;
    private int students;
    
    ...
    //bunch of getters.
}
```

My task is to return Strings for the course(es) with maximum capacity, the course(es) with maximum registered students, the course(es) with most difficulty, the maximum filled percentage, the course(es) with the maximum number of TAs etc...

**Edit 2:**
As requested in the comment section.

List of

```
Course a (name "a", capacity 10, students 5)
Course b (name "b", capacity 20, students 5)
Course c (name "c", capacity 30, students 0)
```

Sorting based on capacity should return "c"

Sorting based on students should return "a b"

Comment: So the task is to extract MAX value from a list?

Comment: 'by different criteria' - means that criteria will be provided as a method argument to specify which of the object properties (value1, value2, etc.) must be used for comparison?

Comment: The task is to extract the Max values from a list, where the max value is defined by different functions defined on the class. Let say we have List<A> as with three elements as a1, a2 and a3. If we sort based on method getValue1() a1 might be the max, if we sort on getValue2() a2 might be the max, if we sort on getValue3() all might be equal so we may need to return all of them.

Comment: Yes, your second comment is what I want to do. The problem occurs due to the fact that there may not be only one, but multiple. To check that I could not think of a way without using methods on instances.

Comment: Is what you want to do to pass `A::getValue1`? instead of `Comparator.comparing(A::getValue1)`?

Comment: If passing that way will help me to use that function as in the line 4 or  8 of the code in the bottom, yes.

Comment: It isn’t necessary to sort the entire list to determine the instances with the maximum value. You can iterate through it once.

Comment: I suggest you provide some sample data and show the expected results.  Make certain the data is sufficient to eliminate any ambiguities in what you are trying to accomplish.  And please use sufficiently defined and populated data structures and classes so others may easily check their own recommendations.

Comment: @mert are you saying that `getValueX()` and `getName()` can be anything?

Comment: @TimMoore Can you clarifty a little more? I think your suggestion is  to iterate over the list and compare the value of whatever the function is needed. However, I guess I would be stuck at the same point. How to pass the class function to compare the values of the instances. Am I right, or missing a point?

Comment: @WJS thanks for the suggestion, I will edit my question. I guess I failed to make my question abstract. I will edit the question and put a simple example of what I tried to mean. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Bohemian, getName is fixed but getValueX can be different functions.

Comment: @mert  I don't see any sample data.  I don't want verbal explanation of input and output.  I would like to see it based on actual data.  So show three or four populated instances of classes and the expected results.

Comment: I have added the requested changes in edit 2 @WJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the getter method and create the Comparator in `getMaxString`:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Foo {
    static class AClass {
        private final String name;
        private final int value1;
        private final int value2;

        String getName() { return name; }
        int getValue1() { return value1; }
        int getValue2() { return value2; }

        public AClass(String name, int value1, int value2) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
        }
    }

    static String getMaxString(Function<AClass,Integer> f, List<AClass> listToSort) {
        listToSort.sort(Comparator.comparing(f));
        int maxValue = f.apply(listToSort.get(listToSort.size() - 1));
        String maxString = listToSort.get(listToSort.size() - 1).getName();

        for (int i = listToSort.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (f.apply(listToSort.get(i)) == maxValue) {
                maxString += ", " + listToSort.get(i).getName();
            }
        }
        return maxString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<AClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new AClass("a", 1,2));
        list.add(new AClass("b", 1,2));
        list.add(new AClass("c", 2,1));
        list.add(new AClass("d", 2,1));
        System.out.println(getMaxString(AClass::getValue1, list));
        System.out.println(getMaxString(AClass::getValue2, list));
    }
}
```

As Tim Moore suggested above, it isn't necessary to sort the list (which has cost O(n*log n)), we can traverse it twice:

```java
    static String getMaxString2(ToIntFunction<AClass> f, List<AClass> listToSort) {
        int maxValue = listToSort.stream().mapToInt(f).max().orElseThrow();
        return listToSort.stream()
          .filter(a -> maxValue == f.applyAsInt(a))
          .map(AClass::getName)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
```

Note that you should test your code with an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems exactly like what I needed. I will implement it in my code and will mark it as an answer after a successful run.

Comment: Not only is a linear search faster than sorting, it also does not require the source list to be mutable. Further, the second version avoids string concatenation within a loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's useful to look at the type signature for [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-), because it sounds like you want to do something similar:

```
static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

The interesting part is the type of `keyExtractor`. Roughly speaking, it's a function from the type of the object you're comparing, to the type of the field you want to use for the comparison. In our case, these correspond to the `A` class and `Integer`. Because these types are fixed in this example, you can declare a method with a signature like this:

```
String getMaxString(Function<A, Integer> property)
```

With the existing algorithm, it can be used this way:

```
String getMaxString(Function<A, Integer> property) {
    listToSort.sort(Comparator.comparing(property));

    int maxValue = property.apply(listToSort.get(listToSort.size() - 1));
    String maxString = listToSort.get(listToSort.size() - 1).getName();

    for (int i = listToSort.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (listToSort.get(i).getValueN() == maxValue) {
            maxString += ", " + listToSort.get(i).getName();
        }
    }
    return maxString;
}
```

However, it isn't necessary or efficient to sort the entire list in order to determine the maximum elements, as this can be determined by iterating through the list once:

```
String getMaxString(Function<A, Integer> property) {
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    StringBuilder maxString = new StringBuilder();

    for (A element : listToSort) {
        int currentValue = property.apply(element);
        if (currentValue > maxValue) {
            // there is a new maximum, so start the string again
            maxString = new StringBuilder(element.getName());
            maxValue = currentValue;
        } else if (currentValue == maxValue) {
            // equal to the existing maximum, append it to the string
            if (maxString.length() > 0) {
                maxString.append(", ");
            }
            maxString.append(element.getName());
        }
        // otherwise, it's less than the existing maximum and can be  ignored 
    }

    return maxString.toString();
}
```

Either way, you can call it using the same method reference syntax:

```
getMaxString(A::getValueN)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Time complexity** O(n) - only one iteration through the dataset.

Hope it'll help.
If something will be unclear fill free to raise a question.

**Main**

```
public class MaxClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<A> comp = Comparator.comparingInt(A::getVal1);

    List<A> items = List.of(new A(1, 8), new A(2, 8), new A(5, 8), new A(5, 27), new A(3, 8));
    items.stream()
            .collect(new GetMax(comp))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

}

Custom collector **GetMax**

```
public class GetMax implements Collector <A, Deque<A>, Deque<A>> {
private final Comparator<A> comp;

public GetMax(Comparator<A> comp) {
    this.comp = comp;
}

@Override
public Supplier<Deque<A>> supplier() {
    return ArrayDeque::new;
}

@Override
public BiConsumer<Deque<A>, A> accumulator() {
    return (stack, next) -> {
        if (!stack.isEmpty() && comp.compare(next, stack.peekFirst()) > 0) stack.clear();
        if (stack.isEmpty() || comp.compare(next, stack.peekFirst()) == 0) stack.offerLast(next);
    };
}

@Override
public BinaryOperator<Deque<A>> combiner() {
    return (stack1, stack2) -> {
        if (stack1.isEmpty()) return stack2;
        if (stack2.isEmpty()) return stack1;
        if (comp.compare(stack1.peekFirst(), stack2.peekFirst()) == 0) {
            stack1.addAll(stack2);
        }
        return stack1;
    };
}

@Override
public Function<Deque<A>, Deque<A>> finisher() {
    return stack -> stack;
}

@Override
public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
    return Set.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
```

}

Class **A** that I used for testing purposes

```
public class A {
private int val1;
private int val2;

public A(int val1, int val2) {
    this.val1 = val1;
    this.val2 = val2;
}

public int getVal1() {
    return val1;
}

public int getVal2() {
    return val2;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "A val1: " + val1 + " val2: " + val2;
}
```

}

**OUTPUT**

```
A val1: 5 val2: 8
A val1: 5 val2: 27
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the information I requested.  Here is what I came up with.

Create a list of Course objects

```
List<Course> list = List.of(
      new Course("a", 10, 5),
      new Course("b", 20, 5),
      new Course("c", 30, 0));
```

Stream the methods and apply them to the list

```
List<String> results = Stream.<Function<Course, Integer>>of(
    Course::getCapacity, 
    Course::getStudents)
      .map(fnc-> getMaxString(fnc, list))
      .toList();
    
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

print the results

```
c
a b
```

I wrote a simple method that takes a method reference and list and finds the maximum. It does not do any sorting.

- allocate a list to hold the names
- set the maximum to the lowest possible
- iterate thru the list applying the method.
- if the value is greater than the current max replace it and clear the current list of names.
- otherwise, if equal, add a new name.
- once done, return the formatted string.

```
    
static String getMaxString(Function<Course, Integer> fnc,
        List<Course> list) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Course obj : list) {
        int val = fnc.apply(obj);
        if (val >= max) {
            if (val > max) {
                result.clear();
            }
            max = val;
            result.add(obj.getName());
        }
    }
    return String.join(" ", result);
}
```